# How to pass this number between functions? C

Tags: c, numbers, arguments, parameter-passing, var

Okay I am kinda confused by the C language.
I need to make a function which gets a number from user and send it to a few other functions (depends on which one is running).
Without it these functions look like this

```
void deflator(FILE** fw_vystup) {
    float ipd, n_hdp = 0.0f, r_hdp = 0.0f;
    do {
        printf("Type in a GDP: ");
        if (1 != scanf("%f", &n_hdp)) {
            vyprazdni_buffer(); // this is just cleaning the buffer
            continue;
        }
    } while (n_hdp <= 0);
    ...
```

So I made it like this

```
void zadani_cisla(float cislo) {
    do {
        printf("Wrong input!");
        if (1 != scanf("%f", &cislo)) {
            vyprazdni_buffer();
        }
    } while (cislo <= 0);
}
void deflator(float cislo, FILE** fw_vystup) {
    float ipd, n_hdp = 0.0f, r_hdp = 0.0f;
    do {
        printf("Zadejte nominalni domaci produkt daneho roku: ");
        zadani_cisla(cislo);
        n_hdp = cislo;

    } while (n_hdp <= 0);
```

And it is still saying wrong input, because the number I type in is not obtained I guess.
Can you see the problem? Thank in advance.

Comment: Please use English looking strings and identifiers!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Why should he do that? He should use identifier names that he is comfortable with.

Comment: Because the code is a message to the readers of SO, and we read this forum in English! (but I am not a native English speaker).

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing your number by reference. For example you need to change the following in your function `deflator`:

```
zadani_cisla(cislo);
```

to

```
zadani_cisla(&cislo);  /* pass by reference */
```

In that way any changed in that variable within the function `zadani_cisla` will be seen in `deflator`

Also within `zadani_cisla` you will need to change the following line:

```
if (1 != scanf("%f", &cislo)) {
        vyprazdni_buffer();
    }
```

to

```
if (1 != scanf("%f", cislo)) {
        vyprazdni_buffer();
    }
```

as the variable `cisla` is already a pointer variable. You will need to change the definition of `zadani_cisla` too

Answer (score 1):

In this loop:

```
 void zadani_cisla (float cislo)
 {
     do {
        printf("Wrong input!");
        if (1 !=  scanf("%f", &cislo)) {
             vyprazdni_buffer();
        }
     } while (cislo <= 0);
 }
```

the printf will always happen at least once.
Your second problem is that floats are passed by value in C, so zadani_cisla can't change cislo in the function that calls it.

Better:

```
 void zadani_cisla (float * cislo)
 {
     do {
        if ((1 == scanf("%f", cislo)) && (*cislo > 0)) break;
        vyprazdni_buffer();
        printf("Wrong input!");
     } while (1);
 }

 zadani_cisla(&cislo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function returning some float:

```
float ask_float(void) {
  float f = 0.0;
  do {
   if (scanf("%f", &f)<=0) 
      printf("wrong float:\n");
   else return f;
  } while(true);
}
```

That you would use as:

```
float f;
f= ask_float();
```

Or you could pass a pointer:

```
void do_ask_float (float*pf) {
  do 
   if (scanf("%f", pf)<=0) 
      printf("wrong float:\n");
   else return;
  } while(true);
}
```

and you would call it as:

```
float f =0.0;
do_ask_float(&f);
```